# Is it possible to authenticate user manually with oauth2

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to authenticate a user with oauth2 to access google drive. I can get the access token required when using AccountManager to retrieve an account and then get the token with:

```
mgr.blockingGetAuthToken(account, ApiConst.DRIVE_AUTH_SCOPE, true);
```

But I want the user to be able to authenticate by providing username and password instead of using the account added to the phone. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

So I have tried to implement the authorization in a WebView. I followed [this example](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/06/oauth-2-0-flow-android/). I have extracted the *code request parameter* but the code used to retrieve the access token seems to be deprecated and not compatible with the packages used by Google Drive SDK. This is the code used to retrieve the access token in the example:

```
AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(new NetHttpTransport(),
new JacksonFactory(),
OAuth2ClientCredentials.CLIENT_ID,
OAuth2ClientCredentials.CLIENT_SECRET,
code,
OAuth2ClientCredentials.REDIRECT_URI).execute();
```

Can this be done in some other way or should I just give up?

Comment: I've seen this https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/ but never worked with it don't know if it can be of any help

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @Alex Thanks I've been looking at the code but can not figure out how to use it.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov The reason is that I want to make it possible for a user that does not own the phone to temporarily log in to access a file on google drive and then log out again.

Comment: In that case they should really use the browser. You could incorporate a WebView in your app to do authentication letting them use username and password.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov ok. I have seen this url used to manually login when working with google docs instead of drive `https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin`. But I read somewhere that ClientLogin is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, it is. It still works though. And it is not OAuth, so it may or may not be supported. It also does not offer fine grained access control.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov I'll try to use a webview instead. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Hey i am searching for the same thing, if you found any solution please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Android, you don't nedd to do all that stuff to authenticate a user.
Just use "GoogleAccountCredential" object to set the user's account:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, scopes);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(theGoogleAccount);
```

Remember that for select user's account you need:

```
startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT);
```

Then you'll be able to initialize Drive:

```
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

Greetings.

Comment: Hey @Cabuxa.Mapache, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error `com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown.` Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151